# Finding a regular expression to get an abritrary expression between 2 fixed expressions

Tags: c#, html, regex, parsing

What am I doing wrong here?

I'm trying to get

```
Someone
Someone Else
Someone W. Bush
Sommone 2
```

from a text file like

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>[...] - Friends</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../html/style.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="nav">
            <img src="../photos/profile.jpg" />
            <ul>
                <li><a href="../index.htm">Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="../html/contact_info.htm">Contact Info</a></li>
                <li><a href="../html/wall.htm">Wall</a></li>
                <li><a href="../html/photos.htm">Photos</a></li>
                <li><a href="../html/synced_photos.htm">Synced Photos</a></li>
                <li><a href="../html/videos.htm">Videos</a></li>
                <li class="selected">Friends</li>
                <li><a href="../html/messages.htm">Messages</a></li>
                <li><a href="../html/pokes.htm">Pokes</a></li>
                <li><a href="../html/events.htm">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="../html/settings.htm">Settings</a></li>
                <li><a href="../html/security.htm">Security</a></li>
                <li><a href="../html/ads.htm">Ads</a></li>
                <li><a href="../html/mobile_devices.htm">Mobile Devices</a></li>
                <li><a href="../html/places.htm">Places</a></li>
                <li><a href="../html/survey_responses.htm">Survey Responses</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="contents"><h1>[...]</h1><div>
        <h2>Friends</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Someone</li>
            <li>Someone Else</li>
            <li>Someone W. Bush</li>
            <li>Someone 2</li>
        </ul>
        <h2>Sent Friend Requests</h2>
        <ul><li>Blah blah</li></ul>
        <h2>Received Friend Requests</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>lakjsdak</li>
            <li>adkasd</li>
        </ul>
        <h2>Friend Peer Group</h2>
        <ul>Starting Adult Life</ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">Downloaded by [...] on Thursday, November 5, 2015 at 9:54pm PST</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So first I need to get the expression sandwhiched between `<h2>Friends</h2><ul>` and `</ul>`. Then I need to get from that expression every instance of a valid name between `<li>` and `</li>`.

The regexes I'm using are

```
    private static readonly Regex _lregx = new Regex(@"<h2>Friends</h2><ul>\w</ul>", RegexOptions.Compiled); 
    private static readonly Regex _fregx = new Regex(@"/<li>([a-zA-Z0-9. ]+)<\/li>/", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

and I'm using them like

```
        using ( StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(newFriendsPath) )
        {
            Match friendsULs = DataReader._lregx.Match(sr.ReadToEnd());
            if ( !friendsULs.Success )
            {
                throw new Exception(String.Format("Couldn't find exactly one piece of HTML matching regex {0}",
                                                    DataReader._lregx.ToString()));                  
            }   

            Dictionary<string, int> friendMap = new Dictionary<string, int>();

            foreach ( Match thisFriendRegex in DataReader._fregx.Matches(friendsULs.ToString()) )
            {
                 // ...
```

but

```
Match friendsULs = DataReader._lregx.Match(sr.ReadToEnd());
```

isn't getting any matches.

Comment: @"<h2>Friends</h2><ul>\w</ul>" - what about whitespaces )))

Comment: Why do you have slashes as first and last char in your regex? Looks like pearl or ruby or ... The reason why your regex doesn't match anything is because you ignored all whitespaces. The second problem is that `\w` will only match one char - but you need all until the closing tag. Maybe this regex `(?s)<h2>Friends</h2>.*?<ul>.*?</ul>` will help.

Comment: If you use `HtmlAgilityPack` this would be easier and more robust.

Answer (score 0):

So many mistakes - better not to test on whole document - test your regexes with small pieces of text and just when it match - test it on big text.

Here I see:

1) `@"<h2>Friends</h2><ul>\w</ul>"` - what about whitespaces? -
at least `@"<h2>\s*Friends\s*</h2>\s*<ul>\s*\w\s*</ul>"` should be

2) what about possible attributes and casing? - should
`@"(?i)<h2[^>]*>\s*Friends\s*</h2>\s*<ul[^>]*>\s*\w</ul>"`

3) what is exactly `<ul>\w</ul>` - may be you think that it's "anything between ul tag limits" - not it is "ONE AND JUST ONE LETTER BETWEEN UL" if you want catch anyting inside tag (only for not nesting tags) - you should use following snippet:
`<ul[^>]*>[\s\S]+?</ul>`

So first regex even before debug and testing should be rewrited to 
`@"(?i)<h2[^>]*>\s*Friends\s*</h2>\s*<ul[^>]*>\s*[\s\S]+?</ul>"`

And again

1) Learn regex well in basics BEFORE try to use it in hard html parsing

2) Test regexes on small pieces of texts

3) HTML with regex - is not bestpractice - better - search and choose tools to convert HTML->XML (where are at least 5 well-known .NET and console tools) and then work with XML (XElement/XPath) and not regexes

Comment: I'm not sure that `<ul[^>]>[\s\S]+?</ul>` will match [`<ul>Foo</ul>`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3cul%5b%5e%3e%5d%3e%5b%5cs%5cS%5d%2b%3f%3c%2ful%3e&i=%3cul%3eFoo%3c%2ful%3e) Maybe you need to change the opening tag to `<ul[^>]*>`.